# How to Sum with indefinite variables?

Tags: summation

I want something like

```
f[n] = Sum[2^Sum[i_k, {k, n}], {i_1, Infinity}, {i_2, Infinity},...{i_n, Infinity}]
```

I'm playing with:

```
Table[i_k, {k, n}]
```

But can't find a way to parse it in the definition.

What's the good way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
With[{n = 5}, 
     Inactive[Sum][a^Sum[K[i], {i, n}], ##] & @@ 
     Table[{K[i], 1, ∞}, {i, n}]]
```

$$\sum_{\mathtt{K[1]}=1}^\infty \sum_{\mathtt{K[2]}=1}^\infty \sum_{\mathtt{K[3]}=1}^\infty \sum_{\mathtt{K[4]}=1}^\infty \sum_{\mathtt{K[5]}=1}^\infty a^{\mathtt{K[1]}+\mathtt{K[2]}+\mathtt{K[3]}+\mathtt{K[4]}+\mathtt{K[5]}}$$

Replace `Inactive[Sum]` with `Sum` to see the actual result of the evaluation.

Comment: OK. ## is the key I want. Thanks.